# Have a white space to the right and repeating image to the bottom right with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

Here's the situation:

This is a screen shot of www.dreamstreetentertainment.com, a site still under construction but live anyway. Don't ask. Customer WANTS that. Suffice it to say, I have a WHITE SPACE to the right and repeating image to bottom right.

The background is in pieces:

1. The moving CLOUD segments over the
2. Background sky
3. The HOLLYWOOD /Los Angeles skyline
4. The road to Hollywood
5. The LAMPS (separate) and CSS set

ISSUE:

The Customer uses 27" Monitors and the image you see, (I use a 22" monitor) is SIMULATED down to 80% of the full screen.

SOLUTION:

How can I fix this side WHITE SPACE and the repeating image lower RIGHT BOTTOM?

Here's the

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    padding-top: 90px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

And the OVERRIDE in custom-ds.css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

BUT the problem still remains.

I have backstretch.js on other sites I've built but this is tricky since the background is split at the HORIZON of the SEA and SKY.

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: As we don't want to parse a full website + when that link breaks this will be of no use for future users, so if you expect to get some qualified answers you'll need to post a minimal code snippet reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top white space is the sky image ending, and the bottom space is the water image ending, and then repeating.

An easy way to go from [image: Original broken background images]

To [image: "Fixed" background images]
without changing the images is to change the following CSS.

```
.waterBackground {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.skyBackground {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Changing the background-size to cover will make the background images fill it's entire parent container, in this case "bg_clouds" which fills the entire viewport.

Comment: GENIUS!  I stupidly had .waterBackground with REPEAT-X. I fixed that and added the background-size: cover and it works like you stated. I feel so ignorant.  The only other issue is that the WHITE now appears only at the bottom when the zoom is reduced which I know (is simulated) on my client's 27" screen.  Somehow, I'll need to STRETCH the entire thing now, but I won't worry about it for now.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad I could help. The bottom white space can be fixed by changing the height on .waterBackground from 490px to 100%

Comment: Thank you Austen. Why did they DOWN VOTE my question and furthermore, why did the moderator believe it's OFF-TOPIC?  That doesn't make sense. What's the point, sir.  Can you UP VOTE my question again, please. YOU HAVE HELPED ME when I overlooked my problem. Isn't that why you and the other folks are here, to help us?  Isn't that the purpose of Stackoverflow: TEAMWORK?